# Django not sending correct json response

Tags: json, django, http

I have set up a simple project and when a post request is made, it is expected to return a response depending on what value the user entered.

I am testing my api logic in postman.

At the moment, no matter what value I enter, the same json response is sent back. This is not the expected logic.

views.py:

```
def function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get("number") == 1:
            print("Number is 1")
            return JsonResponse({'message':'Number is 1'})
        else:
            print("Number is not 1")
            return JsonResponse({'message':'Number is not 1'})
```

Even if the value of number is equal to 1, the message: Number is not 1, is returned.

Postman request:

```
{
    "number": 1
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: `request.POST.get("number")  == "1"`, not 1, but `"1"`

Comment: Hey @RossRodgers, I have tried to enter my data as a number and as a string as well, check my post, I have updated it. Thank You.

Comment: can you add a `print(request.POST)` at the beginning of your function and show us the result?

Comment: Hey @CalebGoodman the result is:  <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: @CalebGoodman I have no idea what is up. I have changed my value in postman, to match my if statement value. Still same result.

Comment: I just added a new answer.  I've actually had the same problem in the past, and didn't realize until you printed `request.POST`.  See below for details.

Comment: Have you tried to set the request header with `Content-Type:application/json`?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo classic case of needing to use `request.body`.  `request.POST` is only used for your own views, and not for webhooks/postman.

Comment: @CalebGoodman, thanks for the hint. Mostly I just force client to send request via json format. There is a tonne of things to know as one matures. Thanks again Caleb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST):

> If you need to access raw or **non-form** data posted in the request, access this through the HttpRequest.body attribute instead.

Since you are sending data that is "non-form" data, you need to use `request.body` instead:

```
import json

def function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        if data.get("number", 0) == 1:
            print("Number is 1")
            return JsonResponse({'message':'Number is 1'})
        else:
            print("Number is not 1")
            return JsonResponse({'message':'Number is not 1'})
```

Comment: Hey @CalebGoodman, I have tried to enter my data as a number and as a string as well, check my post, I have updated it. Thank You.

Comment: Hey @CalebGoodman Thank you bro this has solved the problem. One question, in the line:      data.get("number", 0)          Why is the second argument used, and what is it's purpose?

Comment: @nazam007 it is a default argument in case `data` doesn't have the `number` keyword.  if you try to run `data.get('key')` when `key` doesn't exist, you will get an error unless `.get` has a default.